# Evaluating the integral $\int_{\left|z\right|=\pi}\frac{\left|z\right|e^{-\left|z\right|}}{z}dz$, where the function is not holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I need to evaluate on the circle $\left|z\right|=\pi$ the integral
$$\int_{\left|z\right|=\pi}\frac{\left|z\right|e^{-\left|z\right|}}{z}dz.$$
The function is not holomorphic there. Anyway, I tried to integrate it using polar coordinates and simplyfing the modulo and I got $2\pi e^{-\pi}$ while the result should be $2\pi^2 ie^{-\pi}$.
I'm sure is trivial and I overlooked a stupid error. Can anybody tell me where?

Comment: Possible mistake: forgotten $\pi i$ in $dz$.

Comment: Couple things: 1) when making a post like this please show your work   2) You say the function is not holomorphic "there" - just to be clear, it's  holomorphic on the circle you're integrating on, just not *inside* the circle

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen why do you say it's holomorphic on the circle $|z|=\pi$ can you show me how you got this? Using Cauchy Riemann equation in polar coordinates it seems it's holomorphic only on the circle $|z|=1$

Comment: @Dac0 your function is a scalar multiple of $\int_D z^{-1}$ where $D$ is the circle of radius $\pi$. The integrand is holomorphic everywhere but at the origin, which does not lie on your circle (it's inside it... In the exact middle)

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I used for the Cauchy Riemann equation $\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}=-\frac{i}{r}\frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta}$ and then you have $\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}=-e^{-r}e^{-i\theta}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta}=-\frac{i}{r}e^{-r}e^{-i\theta}$ so should be $r=1$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I think you mislooked the formula, it's not a scalar multiple of $z^{-1}$, this one is: $\int_{|z|=\pi}\frac{\pi e^{-\pi}}{z}dz$, but it's not my function. They happen to coincide on the circle, but since mine is not analytic they do not have to coincide elsewhere (and in fact they don't)

Comment: @Dac0 your integrand is equivalent on the circle of radius $\pi$. Whether you write $|z|$ or you write $\pi$ is irrelevant since they are equal on the circle.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen : Ok, as I stated already, my function is not analytic "there".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let be $z = \pi e^{i\theta}, \theta\in[0,2\pi]$:
$$
\int_{|z|=\pi}\frac{|z|e^{-|z|}}{z}dz =
\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\pi e^{-\pi}}{\pi e^{i\theta}}\pi i e^{i\theta} = 2\pi^2 i e^{-\pi}.
$$
**But...** Cauchy formula can be used:
$$
\int_{|z|=\pi}\frac{|z|e^{-|z|}}{z}dz =
\int_{|z|=\pi}\frac{\pi e^{-\pi}}{z}dz = 2\pi^2 i e^{-\pi}.
$$

Comment: thank you, was what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 7):

If $\gamma(t)=\pi e^{it}$ ($t\in[0,2\pi]$), then\begin{align}\int_{\lvert z\rvert=\pi}\frac{\lvert z\rvert e^{-\lvert z\rvert}}z\,\mathrm dz&=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\bigl\lvert\gamma(t)\bigr\rvert e^{-\lvert\gamma(t)\rvert}}{\gamma(t)}\gamma'(t)\,\mathrm dt\\&=\int_0^{2\pi}\pi e^{-\pi}i\,\mathrm dt\\&=2\pi^2ie^{-\pi}.\end{align}